# What would be the type of `React.createClass` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, reactjs

I am reading [this](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/fcb1b6ab493b0c77d589#formal-type-definitions) and I wonder what would be the type of `React.createClass` / `ReactClass` and `ReactComponent`  in Haskell ?

I am trying to understand the concepts in React, hence the question.

My guess is that this:

`type ReactClass<TProps> = (TProps) => ReactComponent<TProps>;`

would translate to Haskell like:

`data ReactClass tprops = data ReactClass ( tProps -> ReactComponent tProps )`

and

```
type ReactComponent<TProps> = {
  props : TProps,
  render : () => ReactElement
};
```

this would translate to Haskell as:

`data ReactComponent tProps = ReactComponent tProps ReactElement`

but I am unsure.

Could someone please correct me if this is wrong ?

Comment: You can probably take inspiration from purescript. They have a binding written for react.

Comment: You forgot about `this` in translating the function types. `this` provides access to state, props, and refs.

Comment: Hmm... ok, thanks, where would that go ?

Comment: Here is the PS binding: https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-react/blob/master/src/React.purs